# Join Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a problem, i have a table were i keep the incoming and other one were i keep the outgoing records, the thing that i need to do is to group these records by partNumber and have a single output.

```
InTable

PartNo Qty Date
A       1   1/1/13
A       5   1/1/13
B       2   1/1/13

OutTable

PartNo Qty Date
A       2  1/1/13
B       1  1/1/13
C       3  1/1/13


Result Needed

Date 1/1/13

PartNo In Out Total
A      6   2    4
B      2   1    1
C      0   3    -3
```

I have tried something like this but it results on the totals because of the sum(qty), but it does not work any other way.

```
select a.PartNo, sum(b.inQty) as inQty,sum(c.outQty) as outQty, sum(b.inQty)-sum(c.outQty) as total  from 
  (Select PartNo FROM InTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo
  union
  Select PartNo  FROM OutTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo) A
  cross join
  (  
  SELECT PartNo,SUM(Qty) inQty FROM InTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo
  )B
  cross join
  ( 
  SELECT PartNo,SUM(Qty) outQty FROM OutTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo
  )c
  group by a.PartNo
```

There i tried to join three queries, each query individually results in something helpfull, but the problem is when i try to join them, the query will result in something like

```
PartNo inQty outQty total 
A       8       6     2
B       8       6     2
C       8       6     2
```

Any sugestions?, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Full Join

```
SELECT
  Coalesce(I.PartNo,O.PartNo) AS PartNo,
  IsNull(I.Qty,0) AS [In],
  IsNull(O.Qty,0) AS [Out],
  IsNull(I.Qty,0) - IsNull(O.Qty,0) AS [Total]
FROM
  (SELECT PartNo, Sum(Qty) AS Qty FROM InTable WHERE Date = '1/1/2013' GROUP BY PartNo) I
  FULL JOIN
  (SELECT PartNo, Sum(Qty) AS Qty FROM OutTable WHERE Date = '1/1/2013' GROUP BY PartNo) O ON I.PartNo = O.PartNo;
```

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a3cc/10)

Comment: Be careful, it will return a wrong answer when you have multiple rows per PartNo in both tables. Check my answer using aggregation in Derived Tables.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Full Outer Join on two Derived Tables:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(inTab.PartNo, outTab.PartNo) AS PartNo,
    COALESCE(inQty, 0),
    COALESCE(outQty, 0),
    COALESCE(inQty, 0) -  COALESCE(outQty, 0) AS total
FROM 
 (
   SELECT PartNo, SUM(Qty) AS inQty 
   FROM InTable
   WHERE DATE= '01-01-2013'
   GROUP BY PartNo
 ) InTab
FULL JOIN
 (
   SELECT PartNo, SUM(Qty) AS outQty 
   FROM OutTable
   WHERE DATE= '01-01-2013'
   GROUP BY PartNo
 ) OutTab
ON inTab.Partno = outTab.PartNo
```

Comment: Join first and then Group will return a wrong answer, e.g. 2 rows in InTable and 3 in OutTable for PartNo 'A' results in 2*3=6 rows

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `UNION ALL` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`(**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3adde/37)**)

```
;with cte as (
    select partNo, Qty inQty, 0 outQty, mydate
    from inTable
    union all
    select partNo, 0 inQty, qty outQty, mydate
    from outTable
)
select partNo, sum(inQty) inQty,
               sum(outQty) outQty,
               sum(inQty) - sum(outQty) total
from cte
where mydate = '01/01/2013'
group by partNo
order by partNo
```

Results

```
| PARTNO | INQTY | OUTQTY | TOTAL |
---------|-------|--------|-------|
|      A |     6 |      2 |     4 |
|      B |     2 |      1 |     1 |
|      C |     0 |      3 |    -3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `FULL JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN`. You're joining `A` to all the rows returned from `B` and `C`.

```
select a.PartNo, sum(b.inQty) as inQty,sum(c.outQty) as outQty, sum(b.inQty)-sum(c.outQty) as total  from 
  (Select PartNo FROM InTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo
  union
  Select PartNo  FROM OutTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo) A
  FULL JOIN
  (  
  SELECT PartNo,SUM(Qty) inQty FROM InTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo
  ) B ON b.partno = a.partno
  FULL JOIN
  ( 
  SELECT PartNo,SUM(Qty) outQty FROM OutTable
  where date= '01-01-2013'
  group by PartNo
  ) c ON c.partno = a.partno
  group by a.PartNo
```

**Editted**
Changed from a `LEFT JOIN` to a `FULL JOIN` because you want to see a row even if it's only in the intable or only in the outtable.

Comment: wouldn't a FULL OUTER JOIN be better?

Answer (score 0):

```
with part_cte(partno,date)as
(select partno,date from Intable
Union
Select partno,date from OutTable)

,intable_cte(partno,Qty,date)AS
(select Partno,sum(Qty)qty,Date from Intable Group By Partno,Date)

, outtable_cte(partno,Qty,date)AS
(select Partno,sum(Qty)qty,Date from outtable Group By Partno,Date)

select PC.partno,ISNULL(IC.QTY,0),ISNULL(OC.qty,0),PC.Date
From part_cte PC LEFT Join intable_cte IC on PC.partno=IC.partno and PC.date=IC.Date
LEFT Join outtable_cte OC on PC.partno=OC.partno and PC.date=OC.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select isNull(a.PartNo,b.PartNo) as PartNo,
       IsNull(sum(a.qty),0) as InAmt,
       IsNull(sum(b.qty),0) as OutAmt,
       IsNull(sum(a.qty),0)-IsNull(sum(b.qty),0) as Diff
from Intable a
full join OutTable b on a.partno=b.partNo
group by isNull(a.PartNo,b.PartNo)
```

SQLFiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d06d/8

Answer (score 0):

Idid`t saw derivered table so here is my solution ported from Firebired

```
select t.id as [PartNo],
       sum(T.In) as [IN],
       sum(t.Out) as [Out],
       sum(T.inc)-sum(t.decc) as "Total" 
from (
     select p.Partno as [id] ,p.id as [In],0    as [Out],p.Date as dt from PARTSIN p
     union
     select o.Partno as [id], 0    as [In],o.id as [Out,o].Date as dt from PARTSOUT o
) as t
where t.dt='1/1/2013'
group by t.id;
```